# Not able to create a cluster in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, nodes, clustered-index

I have configured two nodes to create a cluster. Both these nodes are working fine separately. When We join them together to form a cluster, Only single node is appearing in cluster.
The elasticsearch.yml of both node is mentioned below:

```
========Node-1======================
cluster.name: "docker-cluster"
network.host: 0.0.0.0
http.port: 9200
node.master: true
node.data: true
discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 2
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["NODE1-IP","NODE2-IP"]

===============Node-2==============

cluster.name: "docker-cluster"
network.host: 0.0.0.0
http.port: 9200
node.master: true
node.data: true
discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 2
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["NODE1-IP","NODE2-IP"]
```

My Requirement is to create a cluster of two nodes and if node1(Master node) fails anyhow, node2 automatically starts working as a Master node.
I have searched a lot but can't find anything wrong in my configuration.

Please help!!!

Comment: which es version u are using ??

Comment: How can you have both the nodes running on same port 9200 ?? can you change the port to 9201 for another node and restart them again ??

Comment: @AmitKhandelwal I am using v7. 0.0

Comment: @AmitKhandelwal though both nodes are two different machines. They can have 9200 port on their machines

Comment: Sorry I thought, you are having both nodes in same machine

Comment: let me know if you are still facing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

i think you have ip issue. try:

```
========Node-1======================
cluster.name: "docker-cluster"
network.host: <instance1-ip>
http.port: 9200
node.master: true
node.data: true
discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 2
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["<instance1-ip>","<instance2-ip>"]

===============Node-2==============

cluster.name: "docker-cluster"
network.host: <instance2-ip>
http.port: 9200
node.master: true
node.data: true
discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 2
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["<instance1-ip>","<instance2-ip>"]
```

Comment: sorry, this is not working...getting below error: "Caused by: java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address",